# What is the contested ability modifier for a 0 Intelligence?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

After an intellect devourer reduces a target's Intelligence score to 0, it can attempt to consume the target's brain with a contested check.

When this scenario came up during a recent Adventurers League game, I gave the affected player a -6 modifier on the contested check. That was a DM judgment call. I've verified that abilities with a 1 score have a -5 ability modifier in the PHB, but 0 is not on the chart.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### An Intelligence Score of 0 or 1 gives a modifier of -5.

We know every even number is a + or - depending on which way above or below the base of 10 we go, so it would look like this:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\text{Score} & \hline \text{Modifier}  \\ \hline 
20 &+5 \\\hline 
18-19&+4\\\hline 
16-17&+3\\\hline 
14-15&+2\\\hline
12-13&+1\\\hline
10-11&0\\\hline
8-9&-1\\\hline
6-7&-2\\\hline
4-5&-3\\\hline
2-3&-4\\\hline
0-1&-5\\\hline
\end{array}

Note that -6 does not happen unless the score somehow drops to a number below 0. If we follow the chart lower, then -1 or -2 would give a -6 modifier, -3 or -4 would give a -7 modifier, and so forth.  Same with scores above 21. 22 and 23 grant a +6 modifier.  Your judgement call was in error, but that's why it's a DM judgement call.  Sometimes the answers do not readily present themselves.  No harm done, and now you know better.

Comment: Thankfully I didn't kill anyone, the player succeeded on the contested check and then the party wiped out the devourers. This chart is great for reference, thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, without a chart, you can use (score-10)/2, rounded down to get the modifier.

Answer (score 5):

### The ability modifier for a score of 0 is −5.

This can be seen in the text immediately following the chart you reference, at the top of the next column (PHB p. 173):

> To determine an ability modifier without consulting the table, subtract 10 from the ability score and then divide the total by 2 (round down).

In your case, `(0−10)/2 = -5`.